# Finding max date if no null value in endDate?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following rows in my database.

```
            profileID |     startDate     |   endDate
   -------------------|-------------------|--------------
    Jr.software eng.  |2012-07-01         |2030-01-01
    ..................|...................|..............
     Eng              |2013-03-28         |2013-03-28
    ..................|...................|..............
     Sr.eng           |2013-04-09         |2013-04-17
    ..................|...................|..............
     CEO              |2012-11-21         |
    ..................|...................|..............
```

above row are stored in my database. I want to get a result like this kinds of conditions.

```
1. If endDate is null then I get only it related startDate.
```

like in above row my expected result is

```
        profileID  |     startDate     |   endDate
   -------------------|-------------------|--------------
     CEO              |2012-11-21         |
    ..................|...................|..............
```

1. If there is no null endDate then I want to get maximum endDate from endDate list.

But if row is like this then

```
           profileID  |     startDate     |   endDate
   -------------------|-------------------|--------------
    Jr.software eng.  |2012-07-01         |2030-01-01
    ..................|...................|..............
     Eng              |2013-03-28         |2013-03-28
    ..................|...................|..............
     Sr.eng           |2013-04-09         |2013-04-17
```

Then my expected result is

```
           profileID  |     startDate     |   endDate
   -------------------|-------------------|--------------
    Jr.software eng.  |2012-07-01         |2030-01-01
    ..................|...................|..............
```

I need a mysql query.

Comment: 1. Please show use the code you've tried so far. 2. Perhaps show us some examples of correct results. 3. Perhaps set up a sqlFiddle.

Comment: the final wished result is only with `Jr.software eng` ?and why just it ?

Comment: because between endDate values 2030-01-01 is maximum. if null value is not present then maximum endDate need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select profileId, Case When endate is NULL then startDate 
       Else Max(EndDate) end  As `Date`
From tablename
```

Comment: maybe u should end case as date

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    l.profileID,
    IF(l.endDate IS NULL,l.startDate,MAX(endDate)) AS Date
FROM mytable AS l
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you looking for something like that :

```
 SELECT profileID,startDate,MAX(endDate) AS endDate
 FROM table1 
 group by profileID
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ead57/10)